# Error loading particle texture in Spritekit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, particle-system, sktexture

My particle texture is correctly showing in the particle system, in SpriteKit. But once the app is started, the image is not recognized :

> SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "XP.png"

I tried to add the image in Images.xcassets, but it is not seen by the particle system. Or just directly in the same folder as the particle effect, but then the image is not recognized once the app is started.

Would you know how to fix this?

Edit:
Here is the code :

```
//2D particle
    func createSKSParticle(str:String)->SKEmitterNode{
        let path : String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(str, ofType: "sks") as String!
        let particle : SKEmitterNode = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(path) as SKEmitterNode
        return particle
    }

    func addParticle(nameParticle: String){
        let p : SKEmitterNode = createSKSParticle(nameParticle)
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "xpPart") //xpPart is in Images.xcassets .... 
        p.particleTexture = texture //HERE is the solution
        self.addChild(p)
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Couple of points to consider... Is the texture you provided a SKTexture or just an image? Have you "cleaned" your project? If the image is not a PNG image, have you tried another file format?

Comment: @sangony Thanks for the comment, I cleaned the project, it is an image, a png. I am using SceneKit, with a spriteKit class which is linked with sceneKit via `overlaySKScene`. The path for the image is correct though, because the particle system shows the correct image. Then, I don't know why it does not read it?

Comment: I don't know your code so perhaps you have already tried this... You have to store your image as a SKTexture. If you are using an image directly it might be the root of your issue.

Comment: @sangony thanks, how do you link the two : SKEmitterNode and the SKTexture? I have edited my post with some code.

Comment: I assume you are setting your particle emitter's texture property with you own image. If that's the case you will have to use something like this: SKTexture *myTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"myPicture.png"];

Comment: @sangony yes but then, how to tell the emitter I want this texture? I added the texture from the particle system window, not by code, and I don't find a way (like a variable `emitter.image = ...`, `emitter.texture = ...`, in the documentation?

Comment: My bad, I thought you were doing all this from code. Not sure how to fix this issue now...

Comment: @sangony Actually you were right, I can just add : `myEmitter.particleTexture = mySkTexture` and the texture would be set in `Images.xcassets` and it works! If you want to post it as an answer, I will mark it. Otherwise, thanks a lot for the support.

Comment: Happy to hear you got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually assigning a texture to the SKEmitterNode should resolve the issue:

```
SKTexture *myTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"myPicture.png"];
```

More information can be found in the [SKEmitterNode docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEmitterNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKEmitterNode/particleTexture).